# Chat (LiveAgent) Customize Response When No Agents Are Available

Tags: lightning, liveagent, chat

I am looking to update the message that is delivered to users when no agents are available to chat.

I am stumped where the messages are being set. I have checked:

- quick message
- $Label.site
- custom labels
- Einstein reply recommendations
- Site's VFP's code
- Embedded button code in WordPress

There doesn't seem to be anything intuitive under "Chat" in settings/quick find box.

Einstein Bot is enabled but we don't have any bots built yet.

Any navigation help or documentation on how to change the *"No agents are available. We can't chat right now. Try again later."* would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Additional branding" feature that is available.

Navigate to Setup> Go to Embedded Service>Embedded Service Deployments>select and View >Edit "Chat Settings" >Edit "Additional Branding".

Then click on the labels tab and you can find that you can customize all labels there.

Example:
[image]

Comment: @Olivia Have you been able to check this in your Org?Happy to answer any follow-up queries. Thanks